# Collinearity of 3 points using linear operations

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any way to verify the collinearity between three points using only linear operations? I.E., non-linear operations like angle validation (sin, cos..) and cross products must be avoided.

This will be used as a constraint in a linear solver.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a general set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or did you have a specific $n$ in mind?

Comment: Hello @OnceUponACrinoid, $n = 2$ is enough for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what operations you want to specifically rule out, but choose two points $P$ and $Q$ and define the equation of the line passing through $P$ and $Q$ as

$$L \equiv P+t(P-Q)$$,

with $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Check if you third point $R$ satisfies the above equation. Typically, this will involve solving a system of $n$ equations for a problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html), three points in the plane are collinear if and only if

$$\left| \begin{array} {ccc}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{array} \right| = 0 .$$

Similarly, three points in space are collinear if and only if

$$\left| \begin{array} {ccc}
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\
x_3 & y_3 & z_3
\end{array} \right| = 0 .$$